# need a javascript scroller automatic buttonless

Tags: javascript, slider, scroller

Does anyone know of a javascript scroller that will scroll a bunch of DIVs in a loop automatically and without buttons. I want to scroll about ten images to the left using my current design. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to quite a few good ones.  I have used several of them.  If you aren't using jQuery yet, then you ought to:

http://webtoolsdepot.com/30-best-jquery-image-and-content-slider-plugins/

http://jquery.com/